# VkApi.audio.Web/android

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. Как многие знают, VK.com 16 декабря перестали отдавать информацию о аудиозаписях. Вот станица, которая отображает аудио https://vk.com/dev/audio.get, но только после нажатия кнопки. Как мне сымитировать нажатие кнопки???Или может подскажете другой способ достать аудио??Спасибо!

Comment: вот другой способ: пишите по адресу api@vk.com, если Ваш продукт: 
1. Является единственным в своем роде, обладает уникальной функциональностью; 
2. Представляет собой полноценный клиент с широкой аудиторией — то есть, поддерживает работу со всеми основными сервисами ВКонтакте, включая новостную ленту и сообщения; 
3. Предполагает использование исключительно свободно распространяемого контента.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, к сожалению, но такой вариант мне не подходит. Просто видел сайты и моб. приложения, в которые получают аудиозаписи и при этом еще и нарушают авторские права. вопрос только как они получаю список аудиозаписей?

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что они что-то нарушают?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, нарушение авторских прав(скачивание музыки).

Comment: так а причем тут авторские права и соблюдать требования из списка выше, получив право на доступ к методам?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я прислушался к вашему совету, но увы, ответ vk отрицательный.